# Как записывать изменения списка, с некоторыми особенностями?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, список

Есть список `a = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]` и список `b =[]`

Список `a = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]` меняется слева направо, по каждому щелчку мыши.

В список `b =[]` требуется записать значения отличные от 40.

Пример:

```
a = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]    b =[]
a = [33, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]    b =[33]
a = [33, 77, 40, 40, 40, 40]    b =[33, 77]
a = [40, 40, 229, 40, 40, 40]   b =[33, 77 ,229]
a = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]    b =[33, 77 ,229]
```

То есть, значения не должны пропадать.

Мой код и пояснения. (Необязательно к просмотру)

```py
def getGrid():
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while True:
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0 :
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
            for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                currentGrid.append(b)
                print(currentGrid)
                currentGrid.clear()
```

По каждому щелчку мыши, код берет пиксель с определенной координаты.
Он записывает значение голубого цвета, и добавляет в список `currentGrid`, который в примере называется `a`. После этого он очищает список, и так по кругу. Значения могут меняться не только слева направо, но в моем случае это будет именно так, по этому можно сказать что они всегда меняются слева направо. Нужен еще один список который будет "запоминать" изменившиеся значение и записывать их.

Comment: _"меняется слева направо, по каждому щелчку мыши"_, — опишите это подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Поправил, извиняюсь за неграмотность. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, в чём проблема. После получения очередной координаты, добавляйте её в список `b`. Если хотите, чтобы координаты в `b` были уникальны, то перед этим проверьте оператором `in` (или можно использовать множества, гарантирующие уникальность).

Comment: Нет, множества здесь использовать не получится, так как насколько я знаю они не допускают дубликаты. В список b записвыется код голубого цвета пикселя. Не буду ничего утверждать, я только новичок, но как я понял, у каждого пикселся есть две координаты - это x и y , а также три числа отвечающих за цвет RGB. Например 255,255,255 это белый. Для своих целей, мне удобно использовать только голубый цвет, b. В этот список b и записываются коды со всех координат. Извиняюсь за отход от темы. Не могли бы вы привести краткий пример, если не трудно, заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Все коды голубого цвета b, записываются в список currentGrid, и меняются с каждым кликом мыши, и проблема в том что нужно как-то один раз сохранить каждый код в другой список, и больше не менять.

Comment: Как смог - восстановил идентацию, но за точность не ручаюсь. Проверьте внимательнее, что именно копируете из редактора кода. Используйте разметку markdown для блоков кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение (функция fucn, остальное - тестирование)

```
import random

def func(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    a.discard(40)
    b += list(a.difference(b))
    return b

a = [40 for i in range(6)]

b = []

for i in a:
    print(f"{a=}, {b=}")
    a.insert(0, random.randint(0, 80))
    a.pop(-1)
    b = func(a, b)

print(f"{a=}, {b=}")

a = [40 for i in range(6)]
b = func(a, b)

print(f"{a=}, {b=}")
```

пример вывода:

```
a=[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40], b=[]
a=[5, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40], b=[5]
a=[20, 5, 40, 40, 40, 40], b=[5, 20]
a=[49, 20, 5, 40, 40, 40], b=[5, 20, 49]
a=[43, 49, 20, 5, 40, 40], b=[5, 20, 49, 43]
a=[53, 43, 49, 20, 5, 40], b=[5, 20, 49, 43, 53]
a=[70, 53, 43, 49, 20, 5], b=[5, 20, 49, 43, 53, 70]
a=[40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40], b=[5, 20, 49, 43, 53, 70]
```

вы вставляете эту функцию, и используете, где нужно

повторю функцию, на всякий случай:

```
def func(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    a.discard(40)
    b += list(a.difference(b))
    return b
```

использование:

```
b = func(a, b)
```

Поправка 1:

здесь, самым наглядным образом показано, как работает функция:

```
def func(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    a.discard(40)
    b += list(a.difference(b))
    return b


b = []
a = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
b = func(a, b)
print(b)  # []

a = [33, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
b = func(a, b)
print(b)  # [33]

a = [33, 77, 40, 40, 40, 40]
b = func(a, b)
print(b)  # [33, 77]

a = [40, 40, 229, 40, 40, 40]
b = func(a, b)
print(b)  # [33, 77, 229]

a = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
b = func(a, b)
print(b)  # [33, 77, 229]
```

Поправка 2:

можно сжать функцию ещё больше:

```
def func(a, b):
    a = set(a) - {40}
    return b + list(a.difference(b))
```

Поправка 3:

```
def func(a, b):
    a = set(a) - {40}
    return b + list(a.difference(b))


def getGrid():
    saveGrid = []
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while True:
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0 :
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
            for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                currentGrid.append(b)
                saveGrid = func(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка 4:
с повторениями:

```
def func(a, b):
    a = list(filter((40).__ne__, a))
    return b + a
```

Поправка 5: (5, карл!!)
с правильными повторениями:

```
def getGrid():
    saveGrid = []
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while True:
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0 :
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
            for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                currentGrid.append(b)
                saveGrid += [b]
                print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка 5.5:

```
def getGrid():
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while 1:
        saveGrid = []
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0 :
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
            for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                currentGrid.append(b)
                saveGrid += [b]
                print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                currentGrid.clear()
```

Правка 6: -_-
если кнопка не нажата, не будет проблем

```
def getGrid():
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while 1:
        saveGrid = []
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0 :
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
            else:
                continue
         
            for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                currentGrid.append(b)
                saveGrid += [b]
                print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка 6.5:

```
def getGrid():
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while 1:
        saveGrid = []
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
                for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                    r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                    currentGrid.append(b)
                    saveGrid += [b]
                    print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                    currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка 7:

```
def getGrid():
    currentGrid = []
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while 1:
        saveGrid = []
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
                for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                    r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                    currentGrid.append(b)
                    saveGrid += [b]
                    print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                    currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка 7.5:

```
def getGrid():
    currentGrid = []
    saveGrid = []
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while 1:
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
                for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                    r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                    currentGrid.append(b)
                    saveGrid += [b]
                    print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                    currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка 8:

```
def getGrid():
    currentGrid = []
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
    state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
    while 1:
        saveGrid = []
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

        if a != state_left:  
            state_left = a
            if a == 1 or a == 0:
                time.sleep(0.3)
                image = ImageGrab.grab()
         
                for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                    r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                    currentGrid.append(b)
                    if b != 40:
                        saveGrid += [b]
                    print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                    currentGrid.clear()
```

Поправка ∞.5:

```
def getGrid():
    currentGrid = []
    state_left_init = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    while 1:
        saveGrid = []
        state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        if state_left != state_left_init and state_left in {0, 1}:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            image = ImageGrab.grab()
            for cord in Cords.cordArray:
                r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
                currentGrid += [b]
                if b != 40:
                    saveGrid += [b]
                print(currentGrid, saveGrid)
                #currentGrid.clear()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109529/discussion-on-answer-by-------).